# AWS Lambda Not Getting Query Parameters

Tags: aws-lambda

I am setting up my first Lambda function on AWS. I use Python 3.6. My code is as follows:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    result = {}
    result["Log stream name:"] = context.log_stream_name
    result["Log group name:"] = context.log_group_name
    result["Request ID:"] = context.aws_request_id
    result["Mem. limits(MB)"] = context.memory_limit_in_mb
    result["size of event"] = len(event)
    result["type of event"] = str(type(event))
    return result
```

I also set up an API Gateway for test Lambda.

However, no matter what query paramters I pass in to the API Gateway, the event is always an empty dict. Below is a sample response. What am I missing?

```
Request: /test/number?input=5
Status: 200
Latency: 223 ms
Response Body
{
  "Log stream name:": "2018/12/05/[$LATEST]9d9fd5dd157046b4a67792aa49f5d71c",
  "Log group name:": "/aws/lambda/test",
  "Request ID:": "dce7beaf-f8c9-11e8-9cc4-85afb50a0e0c",
  "Mem. limits(MB)": "128",
  "size of event": 0,
  "type of event": "<class 'dict'>"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have request mapping templates, you should turn Lambda Proxy integration on.